# Remove top drop menu extension items from admin panel

Tags: configuration, admin-panel, adminmenu

Some of the extensions I've installed on my installation insist on having top drop down menu's in the admin panel that are duplicated in System/Configuration. It's gotten to a point where the items have now started a second row making it somewhat difficult to navigate.

How do you remove **only** these selected top menu items?

Comment: are these new menus just linking to the main configuration page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a menu item you can simply add the following to a `adminhtml.xml` file in your module.

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <first_level>
            <children>
                <second_level>
                    <disabled>1</disabled>
                </second_level>
            </children>
        </first_level>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**For example:**

If you wanted to hide the Catalog->Manage Products for some crazy reason you would replace `first_level` with `catalog` and `second_level` with `products`.

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog>
            <children>
                <products>
                    <disabled>1</disabled>
                </products>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>
</config>
```

I like the idea of creating the custom admin roles but if you want it to be disabled for all users then you way as well remove them.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually an another option, which doesn't require any kind of code surfing -- you can create a new admin user role that instead of "all" contains everything but items you don't want to see. Of course you need to review the ACL list whenever you add new extension or upgrade Magento.

And to all developer reading this forum. Stop adding your crap to main menu! If anything it shows that you really don't understand the way extensions should be developed. Also, it shows that you don't respect your customers!

Comment: yeah drives me nuts having all these top menus. Your suggestion is a good idea but I'd rather remove some altogether. SR

Answer (score 0):

File Name adminhtml.xml located in app/etc/

Code is, as an example I am using Bannerslider extension

```
<menu>
   <bannerslider module="bannerslider">
    <title>Banner Slider</title>
    <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
    <children>
     <items module="bannerslider">
      <title>Manage Banners</title>
      <sort_order>0</sort_order>
      <action>bannerslider/adminhtml_bannerslider</action>
     </items>
    </children>
   </bannerslider>
  </menu>
```

Comment: Will this affect the menu's under System/Config ?

Comment: No, it will work for the menus in top navigation only

Comment: I had some time to look at this, I've updated your answer to reflect the correct path. However in the file you mentioned there is no menu reference.